# Twitter4j, not pulling tweets for particular tweet #tag

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j3.0.5, able to pull tweets for #OWS, #SDC and other things. But for  #SDC13, i am getting 0 tweets wven though there are tweets which i get it when i search in the twitter search for #SDC13. Do we need any permission to pull those tweets for particular #tag other oAuth authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Which mechanism are you using: streaming or search mechanism? Some of the tweets with #SDC13 hashtag might be generated by private accounts which you cannot get the tweets. This might be one of the possible reasons but you should definitely provide which method you are usuing with the search criteria. Then, I can try to help you about your issue.